# UIImageView displays downloaded images from HTTP, but won't display image resource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

In my first View Controller after a user logs in, there is a quick check to see if the user has uploaded a custom image to his account. (If he has, there's a URL in the user's profile data.)

These images are downloaded correctly in my code and they show up beautifully. The problem comes when there is no custom user image, and the VC tries to set the same UIImageView to a default picture (in xcassets). The picture is being loaded into the bundle, as far as I can tell, and it's a valid PNG file.

Here is the snippet for setting the image. If a custom URL is not found, I set the URL parameter string to "nil."

```
-(void) setImageWithUrl: (NSString *) Url Imageview: (UIImageView *) image {

if (Url.length > 4) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Url];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *Profileimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [image setImage:Profileimage];
}
else {
    UIImage *Profileimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultPicture"];

    [image setImage:Profileimage];
}
}
```

This one's driving me nuts, so all weird ideas are welcome. :-)

Let me know if you want me to post any other parts of the code that you think could be a factor.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through in debug? If so, does the flow actually fail at `if (Url.length > 4)` and drop into the `else`? If so, does `Profileimage` get a valid image from `[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultPicture"];`? Find out which question has an answer of "no" and you should find the solution.

Comment: @DonMag The standard debugging drill was a success. It turned out that Url.length was always greater than 4 because of some "extra garbage" that the database sometimes puts in the user profiles. Accounting for this in the code fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like debug-need issue. But why don't you use any image download/cache library, like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)?
It gonna be much efficient and convenient

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it doesn't address why the default image doesn't appear.

(But I'll probably add some optimization like this in a future release: this is just the first planned release of the app right now.)